# Запуск функции с динамической переменной по таймеру

Tags: python, schedule

```
import schedule    
import time 
import random   
    
def rnd1():
    temp = random.randrange(10)
    return(temp)
    
def pr(mess):
    print(mess)

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(pr,str(rnd1()))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

На выходе всегда одно и то же случайное число. Как это можно исправить в данном коде? Должна быть именно функция аргументом которой является вывод другой функции

Comment: С последним условием нельзя сделать

Comment: Хотя есть один способ